# Delimiter ";" doesnt work

Tags: papaparse

I using the following code to achieve the result below

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
   var file = evt.target.files[0];

   var asd = Papa.parse(file, {
       delimeter: ";",
       newline: "",
       quoteChar: '"',
       header: true,
       complete: processResults
   });
}
```

My `.csv` file looks like this:

```
2000;51013;;Kronospan Szczecinek Sp.z o.o.;ul. Waryńskiego 1 78-400 SZCZECINEK;PL6731657551;PLN;PL;;PL;D;51013
```

In the returned file it is written as:

```
2000,51013,,Kronospan Szczecinek Sp.z o.o.,ul. Waryńskiego 1 78-400 SZCZECINEK,PL6731657551 Zweryfikowany poprawnie,PLN,PL,,PL,D,51013
```

Note that the `;` became `,`.

anyone can help me?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: same as input after checking NIP in VIES and adding text verification

Comment: Anyone can help me ? I need fix asap

Comment: You have miss-spelled "delimiter" .  It is "de" (remove) "limit" (limit) "er" (noun suffix).

Answer (score 0):

```
for autodetect delimiter 
delimiter: "",
```

```html
1.
var asd = Papa.parse(file, {
       delimeter: "",//automatic detect delimiter 
       newline: "",
       quoteChar: '"',
       header: true,
       complete: processResults
   });

2. you can remove delimiter from config

var asd = Papa.parse(file, {
       newline: "",
       quoteChar: '"',
       header: true,
       complete: processResults
   });
```